# Performance: Local vs database - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have looked around for a simple answer but |I haven't found it (Though if I am being blind or impatient, I be happy for someone to post me the link)

I have the following code in my repository

```
get
{
    if (context.entity.Local.Count == 0)
    {
        return context.entity;
    }

    return context.entity.Local;
}
```

I know from common sense that the word `local` is not querying the database and getting the result set from memory. However, what I would like to know is, how much faster is fetching the result set from `local` than it is from the database? It is a huge difference?

I am asking as I would like to speed up my web application so I am trying to find weaknesses in the code.

Thanks

Comment: How much faster isn't relevant, what is relevant is if you need the data from the database or not.

Comment: I understand that, but if there isn't a performance hit - why create local? Might as well go to the database - then the developer knows for sure that its the latest server data

Comment: If your suggesting there isnt a speed difference, then that's the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm not suggesting that at all, using Local is probably faster, but not necessarily the right thing to do.

Comment: Ad the answer below states, my common sense is probably way off, thought using local prevents the code going to the database layer (if there is one in EF) but I think I need to read up on local etc!

Comment: Using Local does NOT hit the database, but if you always need the latest data then you shouldn't use it. Also, please read this about performance tuning: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score -3):

First, your common sense makes no sense at all. Local is nothing that is defined at all in EF so it depends on whoever made the repository and could as well refer to something else.

Second - a lot. Easily factor of 1000. THe database is a separate process, involves generating and then parsing SQL. 2x network transfer (or network alyer transfer). Compare that to just reading out a property. 1000 is likely conservative. Not that it may be a lot of time in the database to start with.

It depends on what you DO - but caching in memory and avoiding the database is a valid strategy that can make a lot of difference, performance wise. At the cost of more memory consumption and change synchronization issues. The later is not really relevant for some (never changing) data.

Comment: Local IS defined in EF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.113).aspx. I also take issue with "easily a factor of 1000", there's no way you can say that.

Comment: So now I have an answer (comment) that says speed isnt a factor and yours which states its a lot "factor of 1000, a lot to think about!  thanks!

Comment: You ever get that feeling where you regret asking a question in the first place?.. lol

Comment: @user3428422 Nobody said it wasn't faster, I just said that using Local is situation dependant.

Comment: Actually the qhole question makes no sense because if you refer to the EF local property first figure out what it is. Then realize that you pretty much never need this information. Any sensible query has to hit the database or be more complex. All Local.Count is goof for is knowing how many instances are tracked at the moment. Not something you normally ever care of.

Comment: I think possibly @user3428422 doesn't realise that Local only contains the objects that you have ALREADY retrieved from the database or new ones you have added/updated but not yet saved to DB.

Comment: @DavidG  I know that, as my question says it get its from the memory and not the database, I am running a profiler and it suggests that is correct, I was just asking for speed, but cheers for the info guys